# Viewpager передать позицию(номер) элемента

Tags: java, android

Не могу разобраться как передать позицию строки во фрагмент
Нужно чтобы фрагмент получил число выбранной строки

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public static final String[] TITLES = {"текст1","текст1", "текст1", "текст1",  "текст1"};

public InformTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.i(String.valueOf(position), "Что тут у нас 0 да?");
    InfoTabFragment tabFragment = new InfoTabFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position", position);
    tabFragment.setArguments(b);
    return tabFragment;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}
```

}

пишу int x = getArguments().getInt("position"); он краш

Comment: Почему я получаю текст а не позицию, напишите как получить номер

Comment: лог ошибки приложите пожалуйста

Comment: все, я не там вызывал  int x = getArguments().getInt("position"); (